# How to make a 3x3 img grid and selected one large with next/previous buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm sure that this has been asked before and I have looked and have tried them but none of them seem to work just right.

I'm creating a website for a client and they want a page that has 9 images in a 3x3 grid format which I've got. However, the bit I'm stuck on, is that they want an image to be enlarged if a user clicks on it and have next/previous buttons on the bottom while the background still has the 3x3 grid but is darkened to show that they have selected an image.

What I have at the moment is:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <img src="image1.png">
    <img src="image2.png">
    <img src="image3.png">
    <img src="image4.png">
    <img src="image5.png">
    <img src="image6.png">
    <img src="image7.png">
    <img src="image8.png">
    <img src="image9.png">
</div>
```

I haven't got any `CSS` or `JavaScript` related to it yet as I've tried multiple different things that relate to this but none of them seem to work. Can someone help?

Comment: Search for `lightbox` or try http://ashleydw.github.io/lightbox/#image-gallery

Comment: @Pugazh omg thanks so much :)